# How often should I autodiscover?

Tags: exchange-server, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

We've been using the EWS SDK for a few years now and after many mistakes, we've decided it was time to refactor our code base to reflect what we've learned. One issue we see happen every once in a while is that all EWS call fails because it's pointing to a CAS that is malfunctioning. The solution seems as easy as firing off a background thread every *n* seconds where *n* represents how often we'll autodiscover.

I've scoured the web and can't seem to find any information relating to the matter.

How often should I autodiscover?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the "[How To: Refresh configuration information by using Autodiscover](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn528374%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx)" topic on MSDN:

We recommend that you refresh your user settings by sending a new Autodiscover request after 24 hours have passed since your last Autodiscover request. This time can be adjusted to meet the requirements of your application.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't find that page in my research.